# Calling two persons

Tags: sentence-construction

How do you write the spoken word that you use to call two people by name?

> 1. John! Mike! Come over here.
> 2. John and Mike, come over here.
> 3. John, Mike, come over here.

Which are the above statements correct?

Comment: I'd have no problem with any of those three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three are acceptable but it really depends on the context.

**John! Mike! Come over here** implies urgency or anger. The other two are more 'calm'

Comment: that's a nice answer!